# can i prevent browser back button for a specific page only in Reactjs v18 with router-dom v6?

Tags: reactjs

> Hello, i'm trying to prevent the browser's back button from the user for a specific page only.

## **page1.jsx**

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.clear();
  history.replace("/dashboard/customers")
}, []);
```

// Expected to prevent this page from the browser's back button.

// but i have got this error:

**Unexpected use of 'history'**

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post to use [markdown](/markdown) properly? You've used literally everything except normal text.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `window.history.replace("/dashboard/customers")` to avoid this issue. Because `window` is a global variable, `history` is a property of `window`. If you use `history` directly, eslint tool will throw this warning.